# How we can use foreground service in android 12 for trip detection

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, foreground-service

I am using foreground service for detect the trip in background. Everything is working fine in android 11 and below 11 version.
but When I test the app in android 12, then background operations is not performed properly. Service is always destroying in background. how we detect the trip in android 12. Because it is important for trip detection. can anyone suggest me to solve this problem.

Comment: You may need to consider using a [workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to schedule background tasks instead.

Comment: I had tried with work manager but it was not working . please suggest me any other solution.

Comment: Can we use work manager for long term background operations. If yes then how?

Comment: You can use a `WorkManager` for long term background operations. Try to make an attempt at the code using this guide:[WorkManager basics](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-basics-beba5). Edit your question with your code attempt if it doesn't work.

Comment: Above link is now working. this showing 404 error.

Comment: [Android WorkManager tutorial](https://flexiple.com/android/android-workmanager-tutorial-getting-started/)

Comment: Work Manager is not working when the app is completely killed. Please provide any demo .it will be very helpful for me